# Why does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{8^n+10^n}{9^n}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{8^n+10^n}{9^n}$$

Why is it converging?

Comment: It doesn't. The terms don't go to $0$.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: The terms tend to $\infty$ since $\left(\frac89\right)^n\to0$ and $\left(\frac{10}9\right)^n\to\infty$.

Comment: Note that ${10 \over 9} > 1$, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{8^n+10^n}{9^n} \ge \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{8^n+10^n}{9^n} > N$ for any $N$ and so  cannot converge.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{10^n}{9^n}=\left(\frac{10}{9}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac19\right)^n\to\infty$$ hence a fortiori $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{8^n+10^n}{9^n}\to\infty$$ The series is not convergent.